# How to bind to ContentControl.Content's attached property

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a modular WPF app - Shell, Module1, Module2, Module3.
Each module has views defined like this:

```
<UserControl>

    <TextBox x:Name="DefaultControl"/>
    
    <UserControl.Tag>
        <Binding ElementName="DefaultControl"/>
    </UserControl.Tag>
</UserControl>
```

Shell has the MainView, which uses WPFToolkit BusyIndicator control. MainView is defined like this:

```
<Window>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding ElementName=MainRegion, Path=Content.DataContext.IsBusy}"
                        FocusAfterBusy="{Binding Path=Content.Tag, ElementName=MainRegion}">
                        
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainRegion">
        </ContentControl>
        
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
</Window>
```

BusyIndicator.FocusAfterBusy is meant to set focus on any view's element named DefaultControl, when IsBusy becomes False.
It works fine when using Tag property for binding.
But now I want to use a simple attached property called DefaultControl (object) for that.
View becomes like:

```
<UserControl>

    <TextBox x:Name="DefaultControl"/>
    
    <ext:FocusExtension.DefaultControl>
        <Binding ElementName="DefaultControl"/>
    </ext:FocusExtension.DefaultControl>
</UserControl>
```

How should I change the Path in BusyIndicator.FocusAfterBusy="{Binding Path=Content.Tag, ElementName=MainRegion}", to bind to MainRegion.Content's attached property (DefaultControl)?
Attached property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultControlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "DefaultControl",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(FocusExtension),
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static object GetDefaultControl(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (object)obj.GetValue(DefaultControlProperty);
}

public static void SetDefaultControl(DependencyObject obj, object value)
{
    obj.SetValue(DefaultControlProperty, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FocusAfterBusy="{Binding Path=Content.(ext:FocusExtension.DefaultControl), 
    ElementName=MainRegion}"
```

Comment: XAML editor for (ext:FocusExtension.DefaultControl) shows "Property 'DefaultControl' is not attachable to elements of type 'object'". Project compiles, runs - but it doesn't set focus like it did with Tag. Output window shows nothing

Comment: The editor in Visual Studio isn't smart enough to figure this out. It doesn't matter though. Why would it set focus? This is how you bind to an attached property.

Comment: IC ... it would set focus, well, because BusyIndicator.FocusAfterBusy is intended to do that. And it works fine when using Tag. Other common methods to set focus won't work - DefaultControl textbox only gets logical focus. My guess is that BusyIndicator after being shown/hidden still keeps it

Comment: I cannot see how your original question is related to focus. Aren't you asking on how to bind to an attached property of the `Content` of the `ContentControl`?

Comment: I was only answering your question: Why would it set focus? :)